# Implicit resolution and their parameter type inference in scala

Tags: scala, implicits

Are there any good sources on how implicit resolution works, especially regarding type inference and order (if any) in which implicits are searched for all implicit parameters?

First, of course I read Scala Language Specification, so I understand (or I think) the basics, like where the compiler searches for implicits. Whenever however I try to do anything a little more advanced, like recursive implicits, I always encounter supernatural problems and working with them seems like praciticing experimental magic. Even keeping all implicits together in a companion object and thus eliminating all difficult problems with conflicts, a little change in the code, which shouldn't change the semantics according to specs, sometimes makes a difference between compiling and not compiling.

I remember a case where the compiler couldn't find an implicit for `Companion`, but introducing `import Companion._` before the call made it compile, and object Companion had only implicit defs returning Companion instances.

I had a case where a code structured this way:

```
object ADT {

class Evidence;
object Evidence {
    class ParticularEvidence extends Evidence
    object ParticularEvidence {
        implicit def ... :ParticularEvidence
    }
}
...
def f(...)(implicit e:ParticularEvidence) = ...
...
f(...)
```

didn't compile, but moving the implicits defs (the only ones for ParticularEvidence) from ParticularEvidence to parent Evidence object made them visible.

After some trial and error I understood that the resolution logic is pretty limited and constructs of this class for example:

```
implicit def f[X, Y, Z](x :X)(implicit e1:Evidence1[X, Y], implicit e2:Evidence[Y, Z]) :Y
...
val x :X = ...
val z:Z = x
```

where evidence classes are invariant to their type parameters will rarely compile even if there's exactly one type Z for which such implicit values exist. But I have no idea why the following is a problem:

```
/** Stub for the purpose of this example **/
sealed abstract class ||[+A,+B]
case class LeftVariant[+A](left :A) extends ||[A, Nothing]
case class RightVariant[+B](right :B) extends ||[Nothing, B]


object SupportingEvidence {

    /** C is an Atom and U==C or U is a type union explicitly containg C */
    sealed class ComponentOf[C, U] protected[SupportingEvidence]() extends SupportingEvidence

    final class Atom[T] protected[SupportingEvidence]() extends ComponentOf[T, T]

    implicit def atom[T](implicit ev :Not[T <:< ||[_,_]]) = a.asInstanceOf[Atom[T]]

    implicit def leftComponent[A, B, C](implicit ev: C ComponentOf A): C ComponentOf (A || B) =
        ev.asInstanceOf[ComponentOf[C, A || B]]

    implicit def rightComponent[A, B, C](implicit ev: C ComponentOf B, but: Not[C ComponentOf A]): C ComponentOf (A || B) =
        ev.asInstanceOf[ComponentOf[C, A || B]]

    private[this] val a = new Atom[Nothing]


    type Something[X] = Not[X<:<Nothing]


    /** T = U - C, calculated as follows:
      *  U = A || B => A - C || B - C
      *  U <: C => Nothing
      *  else => U
      */
    final class Minus[U, C, T] protected[SupportingEvidence]() extends SupportingEvidence

    object Minus {
        implicit def nothing[U, C](implicit atom :Atom[U], conforms :U ConformsTo C) :Minus[U, C, Nothing] =
            certify[U, C, Nothing]

        implicit def self[U, C](implicit atom :Atom[U], diff :Not[U ConformsTo C]) :Minus[U, C, U] =
            certify[U, C, U]

        implicit def left[A, B, C, T](implicit left :Minus[A, C, T],
                                      leftSomething :Not[C ConformsTo A],
                                      rightNothing :C ConformsTo B) :Minus[A || B, C, T] =
            certify[A || B, C, T]

        implicit def right[A, B, C, T](implicit leftNothing :C ConformsTo A,
                                       right :Minus[B, C, T]) :Minus[A || B, C, T] =
            certify[A || B, C, T]

        implicit def union[A, B, C, L, R](implicit atom :Atom[C],
                                          leftSomething :Not[C ConformsTo A],
                                          rightSomething :Not[C ConformsTo B],
                                          left :Minus[A, C, L],
                                          right :Minus[B, C, R]) :Minus[A || B, C, L || R] =
            certify[A || B, C, L || R]

        private[this] def certify[U, C, T] = m.asInstanceOf[Minus[U, C, T]]

    }

    private[this] val m = new Minus[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
}



final class ConformsTo[-X, +Y] protected[ADT] (protected[ADT] val cast :X=>Y) //extends Conversion[X, Y]

object ConformsTo {
    import SupportingEvidence._

    private def apply[X, Y](fun :X=>Y) :ConformsTo[X, Y] = new ConformsTo(fun)

    implicit def directlyConformsTo[X, Y](implicit ev :X <:< Y) :ConformsTo[X, Y] =
        ConformsTo(ev.apply _)

    implicit def conformsToLeft[X, A, B](implicit atom :Atom[X],
                                         conform :ConformsTo[X, A],
                                         only :Not[ConformsTo[X, B]]) :ConformsTo[X, A || B] =
        ConformsTo((x :X) => LeftVariant(conform.cast(x)))

    implicit def conformsToRight[X, A, B](implicit atom :Atom[X],
                                          conform :ConformsTo[X, B],
                                          only :Not[ConformsTo[X, A]]) :ConformsTo[X, A || B] =
        ConformsTo((x :X) => RightVariant(conform.cast(x)))

    implicit def conformsToBoth[X, A, B](implicit atom :Atom[X],
                                         left :ConformsTo[X, A],
                                         right :ConformsTo[X, B]) :ConformsTo[X, A || B] =
        ConformsTo((x :X) => LeftVariant(left.cast(x)))

    implicit def alternativesConform[A, B, Y](implicit left :ConformsTo[A, Y], right :ConformsTo[B, Y],
                                              nonDirect :Not[(A || B) <:< Y]) :ConformsTo[A || B, Y] =
        ConformsTo((x :A || B) => x match {
            case LeftVariant(l) => left.cast(l)
            case RightVariant(r) => right.cast(r)
        })

}
}

/** Implicit value for Not[T] exists <=> there's no implicit value for T in scope */
final class Not[+T](override val toString :String)

object Not {
    private[this] val nice = new Not[Nothing]("default")
    private[this] val mean = new Not[Nothing]("conflict")

    implicit def conflict[T](implicit ev :T) :Not[T] = mean
    implicit def default[T] :Not[T] = nice
}

//test Minus
class SA
class SB
implicitly[Minus[SA || SB, Nothing, SA || SB]] //unhelpful divergent expansion error
```

I am experimenting here with boxed type unions (||[A, B] is basically a glorified Either with transparent flattening of the structure and hidden left/right options). Minus is part of type arithmetic I want to implement: in the last line I demand that the compiler provides evidence that SA||SB - Nothing = SA||SB. More generally, I expect an implicit minus[A,B,C] to exist if and only if C is the smallest type containing all values from A and none values of B. What's more, I expect it to find sch evidence even if C is unknown, only from A,B, so I can try to implement implicit evidence allowing for automatic conversion of any type union to some normalized form. eventually, I want to find such combination of implicit methods providing Normalized values, that I will be able to write something like this:

```
def normalize[A,B,N](v :A || B)(implicit :Normalized[A || B, N]) :N
val a :Int || java.sql.Date || Int || String || java.lang.Date = ...
val n = normalize(a) //n is of type Int || java.lang.Date || String
```

So the compiler, with a help of set of rules enforced by implicit methods, should be able to simplify a union type by getting rid of parts which are dominated by other parts. For that, I must be able to i plement set subtraction on types.

I know that I'm probably far in enemy teritory with this and any compiler change might break the whole program depending on this, but I treat it primarily as a puzzle and a proof of concept. Once I get to know what's possible, I will start to think what's sensible.

So the specific question is: does anybody know what's exactly wrong with the above code and can if it can be fixed?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: aargh, sorry, fire drill interrupted me and I forgot to sum up with the question: 1. can anybody make the above compile? 2. is there any source I can read about what works, how it works and what are the chances it will still work within half a year?

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete. Or do you mean the ellipses to indicate that code is missing?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to paste only relevant fragments of the code and forgot to add || class stub (real implementation actually does something, but it should be irrelevant to this question). Ellipses typed without thought to signify that separated parts come from different files, shouldn't matter. implicit resolution for all given classes but Minus work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I rewrote this answer to focus on `Minus`:

I swap the implicit `ConformsTo` rule in minus. In `nothing` and `self` you check `U ConformsTo C`. You should do the same in `left` and `right`:

```
final class Minus[U, C, T] extends SupportingEvidence

object Minus {

  implicit def nothing[U, C](implicit atom: Atom[U], conforms: U ConformsTo C): Minus[U, C, Nothing] =
      certify[U, C, Nothing]

  implicit def self[U, C](implicit atom: Atom[U], diff: Not[U ConformsTo C]): Minus[U, C, U] =
      certify[U, C, U]

  implicit def left[A, B, C, T](implicit left: Minus[A, C, T],
                                leftSomething: Not[A ConformsTo C],
                                rightNothing: B ConformsTo C): Minus[A || B, C, T] =
      certify[A || B, C, T]

  implicit def right[A, B, C, T](implicit leftNothing: A ConformsTo C,
                                 right: Minus[B, C, T]): Minus[A || B, C, T] =
      certify[A || B, C, T]

  implicit def union[A, B, C, L, R](implicit //atom: Atom[C],
                                    leftSomething: Not[A ConformsTo C],
                                    rightSomething: Not[B ConformsTo C],
                                    left: Minus[A, C, L],
                                    right: Minus[B, C, R]): Minus[A || B, C, L || R] =
      certify[A || B, C, L || R]

  def certify[U, C, T] = nothingMinusNothingIsNothing.asInstanceOf[Minus[U, C, T]]

  val nothingMinusNothingIsNothing = new Minus[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
}
```

It allows you to check:

```
trait Animal
trait Car
trait Cow extends Animal
trait Barking
class Dog extends Animal with Barking

implicitly[Minus[Dog, Animal, Nothing]]
implicitly[Minus[Dog, Barking, Nothing]]
implicitly[Minus[Cow, Barking, Cow]]
implicitly[Minus[Cow, Animal with Barking, Cow]]

implicitly[Minus[Dog || Cow, Barking, Cow]]
implicitly[Minus[Cow || Dog, Barking, Cow]]
implicitly[Minus[Cow || Car, Barking, Cow || Car]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'll have a look tomorrow at work. Does Minus work though? ComponentOf and ConformsTo worked for me. As in javadocs, the goal was to provide arithmetic on types seen as sets of values, and in Minus[A, B, C] C is the smallest type containing all values of A and no values of B. As expected, implicitly[Minus[A, A, Nothing]] and implicitly[Minus[A, Nothing, A]] compile, but Minus[A||B, Nothing, A||B] doesn't. I wanted to make the compiler deduce type C in Minus[A,B,C] when A,B are known by searching for an implicit and use the deduced type in implementation of Normalized.

Comment: 'smallest' in the loosest sense, one of permutations of C1,...,C2 such that C = C1||...||C2. As long as an implicit value exists for only one such permutation, I'm fine with it. Therefore true normalization will not be possible, as I would probably end up with implicit values Normalized[Int||String, Int||String], Normalized[String||Int, String||Int] - second type parameters would be probably different, while they should be the same in true normalization. I have no idea though how to introduce complete order on types that can be verified in runtime.

Comment: I would like to understand motivation behind these changes: In what way the scope in which a class and its companion object with implicits are defined affects implicit resolution? Why constructor visibility matters if the instances are only created by the companion object? I don't want any false evidence. What is differentiation in package object? (I have to read about it I guess). Ideally, I'd like to export only a handfull of classes, but all evidence must be visible from client code, so I can't make them protected; that's why I had several nested scopes to minimize namespace pollution.

Comment: Okay I found your bug in Minus: you wrote `implicit def right[A, B, C, T](implicit leftNothing: C ConformsTo A, right: Minus[B, C, T]) : Minus[A || B, C, T]` instead of `... implicit leftNothing: A ConformsTo C ...`. Now I can compile: `implicitly[Minus[Cow || Dog, Barking, Cow]]` and `implicitly[Minus[Cow || Car, Barking, Cow || Car]]`

Comment: What I said about the scope is not a rule rather a debugging trick. When I write implicits I put them all in the same scopes, and when it work I organize the scopes. Also I spotted the bug by triyng to call `Minus.right` myself, and the type error `required: evidence.ConformsTo[animal.Barking,animal.Dog]` gave me the hint.

Comment: Oh god, I'm so sorry, so much work on your part because of such a stupid mistake! Thanks a bunch, I must be really tired, I really thought the problem was in implicit type resolution! I'll check at work on monday if this will compile: def test[A,B,C](a:A,b:B)(implicit e:Minus[A,B,C]) {}; val cod :Cow||Dog = LeftVariant(new Cow); test(cod, new Cow)   - if so, I'm halfway home! Many thanks!